# How to change layout content the same throughout all erb files

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am new to using sinatra 
I have in my layout erb file a navbar that stays consistent through all my pages using yield
At the same time I have this h1 tag above the nav bar that I want to keep changed throughout all my erb pages

ex:

```
<body>
<nav>
<div id = "row">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div>

    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About Us</li>
        <li>Gallary</li>
    </ul>
    <%= yield %>
</nav>
</body>
```

How do I manipulate that h1 tag to print different strings throughout all my pages? Do I store it in my rb file within a method?

Answer (score 1):

Refer here - http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/content_for

I think in your view you can

```
<% content_for :title do %>
  "Your cool page title"
<% end %>
```

In your layout.erb

```
<div id = "row">
    <h1><%= yield_content :title %></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: is that relative to the how the erb positions its content? Like I notices when I yield my nav bar and add a h1 tag in a separate page for a title it sets it below the nav bar.

Comment: `yield` will "attach" so to speak in the manner you call it. `content_for` adds an "id" so to speak again and the `yield_content` for it attaches where you refer it. Have you tried it?

Comment: I was given a no method error. Do I need something in my main.rb file for was those blocks only for the views and layout?

Comment: Maybe in your view you can add the h1 tag inside content_for and call the yield_content inside row in your layout.